# Javascript - getting the time value before an iframe starts loading

Tags: javascript

I load my frames like so:

```
$url = array();
$url[] = 'url1.com';
$url[] = 'url2.com';
echo "<div id='content'> </div>";
foreach($url as $u){
   echo '<div class="frame_container">
            <iframe onload="time_after_frame_loaded();" width="200" height="200" id="myiframe" src="http://www.'.$u.'"></iframe>
            <div class="loadingtime"></div>
         </div>';
}
```

The `onload` event gets me the time value AFTER the frame has loaded:

```
function time_after_frame_loaded(){
frame_loaded = (new Date()).getTime();
//console.log(frame_loaded);
}
```

How do i calculate the time BEFORE each frame starts loading?

EDIT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function time_after_frame_loaded(begin_time) {
    var result = 0; //trying to reset the value for each frame
    var frame_loaded = (new Date()).getTime();
    // console.log("Begin: " + begin_time + ", Loaded: " + frame_loaded);
    result = (frame_loaded - begin_time)/1000;
    console.log(result + "sec");
}
</script>
```

output when loading 4 urls:

```
6.265sec 
6.671sec
8.905sec 
10.077sec
```

Comment: Did you try just calling the function outside of onload?

Comment: Your looping assigns multiple `<iframe>` elements the same `id` attribute - "myiframe". That's not good.

Answer (score 1):

Use this PHP:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($url as $u){
    echo '<div class="frame_container">
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  (function () {
                      var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                      iframe.width = "200";
                      iframe.height = "200";
                      iframe.id = "myiframe' . $i . '";
                      var begin_time = (new Date()).getTime();
                      iframe.onload = function () {
                          time_after_frame_loaded(begin_time);
                      };
                      iframe.src = "http://www.' . $u . '";
                      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                  })();
              </script>
              <div class="loadingtime"></div>
          </div>';
    $i++;
}
```

And this Javascript:

```
function time_after_frame_loaded(begin_time) {
    var frame_loaded = (new Date()).getTime();

    console.log("Begin: " + begin_time + ", Loaded: " + frame_loaded);
}
```

I'm not sure it's the most efficient method, but it should get the correct "begin" time and associate it with each iframe.

Comment: I am getting too high values for some reason. Im trying to get loading time for each frame (`result = (frame_loaded - begin_time) / 1000`). The result value keeps on adding itself to the previous value (if the 1st frame result value was ~2, the next one wil be more than 2, the next after that will be more than the previous and so on (i was loading 3 frames and the last result value was ~15 witch cant be right)).

Comment: @Edgar Hmm interesting. I thought I took care of that. Well, I just edited my answer - give that a try and let me know if it fixes it. But you're right that things are acting up

Comment: i think it works correctly but it keeps on adding the result values. I wrote this in javascript - `result = (frame_loaded - begin_time)/1000; console.log(result + "sec");`. The result is the loading time of each frame in seconds. When i load more than 1 frame it works like so - value1 = 2.14, value2 = 1,41+ value1, value3 = 0,61 + value2 (keeps adding the previous value);

Comment: @Edgar Ahh okay. Did you know that variables should be declared with `var`? So instead of using `result = blah blah blah...;`, use `var result = blah blah blah...;`

Comment: yep im using the var, but still doesnt work how i want it to. Eddited the OP with the javascript

Comment: @Edgar Yeah sorry, that was a dumb suggestion of mine, I'm not sure why I suggested it. Let me keep looking

Comment: @Edgar What values are you getting when you put this in your `time_after_frame_loaded` function - `console.log(new Date(begin_time));` ?

Comment: When i put console.log(new Date(begin_time)); i get these values: `Mon Apr 08 2013 09:56:47 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)` `Mon Apr 08 2013 09:56:47 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)` `Mon Apr 08 2013 09:56:47 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)` `Mon Apr 08 2013 09:56:47 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)`

Comment: @Edgar Okay, that's what I thought and was hoping. That means the `begin_time` values are being set/passed correctly (since they're all actually exactly the same date/time). Can you update your question and show all of the related code you're using now?